# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Xrm.ActivityParty>'

Tags: c#, .net, string, type-conversion

I've received two errors pointing to the script down below:

Receiving error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to
>   `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Xrm.ActivityParty>`    FOR To =
>   emailData.To,

And also receiving error:

> Cannot initialize type 'Xrm.ActivityParty' with a collection
>   initializer because it does not implement
>   'System.Collections.IEnumerable'   FOR From = new ActivityParty{

Here  is the code:

```
foreach (var file in unReadFiles)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem emailData = oApp.Session.OpenSharedItem(file);

    try
    {
        Email scrapedMessage = new Email
        {
            Subject = emailData.Subject,
            Subcategory = EmailHelper.ScrapeMethod.Manual.ToString(),
            Description = emailData.HTMLBody,
            To = emailData.To,
            From = new ActivityParty{ 
                    emailData.Sender.Address
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the gray check mark beside the answer. Check this link to know How does accepting an answer work: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `To` is an `IEnumerab<ActivityParty>` and your are trying to just assign a simple string to it. You can use an array like this:

```
To = new [] {new ActivityParty { To= emailData.To }}
```

Also for your `From` property, you need to declare the property name:

```
From = new ActivityParty
{ 
    Address = emailData.Sender.Address
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334461.aspx) documentation you need to create Activity party class variable to assign your 'To' and 'From' properties.

```
 private Guid _contactId;
    private Guid _userId;
// Create the 'From:' activity party for the email
                ActivityParty fromParty = new ActivityParty
                {
                    PartyId = new EntityReference(SystemUser.EntityLogicalName, _userId)
                };

                // Create the 'To:' activity party for the email
                ActivityParty toParty = new ActivityParty
                {
                    PartyId = new EntityReference(Contact.EntityLogicalName, _contactId)
                };
 To = new ActivityParty[] { toParty },
 From = new ActivityParty[] { fromParty },
```